# Unchecking a boolean field on form render

Tags: 8, forms

I have a content type that has a boolean field (checkbox) that editors need to always re-check on saving a new revision, if they want the value to still be `true`. Otherwise, it would be saved as `false`.

I'm using a `hook_form_node_form_alter` to modify the `$form` before the page is shown to the Editor.

```
public function my_module_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) 
{
   $form['field_my_boolean_field']['#value'] = 0;
}
```

I've tried something similar to the above and have also tried `#checked` and `#default_value` in place of `#value` but nothing seems to work. The checkbox always renders checked (as it is saved in the database). How can I uncheck this boolean field when the form is rendered? Note that I do *not* want to change the actual value of the field for this node, just make it unchecked in the UI when the form for this content is shown.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_prepare_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_prepare_form/8.5.x) to change entity values before the entity form is built:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_prepare_form() for Nodes.
 */
function mymodule_node_prepare_form(\Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node, $operation, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  if ($node->getType() != 'my_content_type') {
    return;
  }
  if ($operation == 'edit') {
    $node->field_my_boolean_field->value = 0;
  }
}
```

This changes the value of the field for this node, but only temporary as long as the user doesn't submit the form.